# How to change hadoop distcp staging directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

when I ran command

```
hadoop distcp -update hdfs://path/to/a/file.txt hdfs://path/to/b/
```

I got an Java IOException:

```
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /some/.staging/directory
```

However, I don't want to use "/some/file/path" as a temporary staging directory, how can I change it to another directory I want?

Comment: I think I've found it, it's "yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir" configuration in mapred-site.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's controlled via `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir` (defaulting to `/user` in my install).